# How to install R with homebrew with Java support?

Tags: osx-lion, java, homebrew, r

I have been trying to install the R language with Homebrew but when I install Java packages like iplots I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘iplots’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Note: On Mac OS X we strongly recommend using iplots from within JGR.
Proceed at your own risk as iplots cannot resolve potential ev.loop deadlocks.
'Yes' is assumed for all dialogs as they cannot be shown without a deadlock,
also ievent.wait() is disabled.
2012-01-29 16:24:57.870 R[29384:c07] Apple AWT Java VM was loaded on first thread -- can't start AWT.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'iplots', details:
  call: .jnew("org/rosuda/iplots/Framework")
  error: java.lang.InternalError: Can't start the AWT because Java was started on the first thread.  Make sure StartOnFirstThread is not specified in your application's Info.plist or on the command line
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/User/Library/R/2.14/library/iplots’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘iplots’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘iplots’ is not available for package ‘JGR’
* removing ‘/Users/User/Library/R/2.14/library/JGR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘JGR’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have been told that R needs to be installed with the following command `NOAWT=1 R CMD INSTALL`. I'm not entirely sure how to do this with Homebrew.

I tried using `brew install r --NOAWT=1` with no luck.